# Using Flutter webview prevent accidently using sliders while scrolling on the webview page

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a really annoying problem.

I am using webview in Flutter and a have a page that is responsive and designed for mobile usage, so when I scroll the page with my phone I accidentally tap on the sliders on the page, and they get affected and change which prevents me from scrolling and of course left and right gesture is detected even tho I am scrolling.

To further explain what I mean, go to this page on **mobile** https://material-ui.com/components/slider/ and keep scrolling in by having your finger in the middle or tap on a slider and try to scroll down, you won't be able to and the slider will change value.

**Is it possible to use Flutter gestures to prevent this even tho the whole application is a webview widget?**

Comment: you want slider to not slide? Wrap it in AbsorbPointer widget

Comment: The problem is that the whole app is just a WebView widget, so I would not be able to do that, the sliders are from the website that is shown in the WebView

Comment: you could disable the scroller, by modifying scroller tag eg. remove id of it

Comment: I will need the scroll, because the page I am using is scrollable, I am currently in a deadlock about this